# How to call a different method(written in second class) run from different class(first class)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

- First project --- in the Eclipse IDE -- Selenium Project

  ```
      public class StandLib () {

          public string URL = "http://www.google.com";

                  Standlib objAutomation = new Standardlib();

                  public static void main (String args[]) 
                  {
                      objAutomation. testlaunch(URL);
                  }
      }
  ```
- Second proj  --- in the Eclipse IDE  -- Selenium Project

  ```
      public class BusinesLib() extends  StandLib {

              public void testlaunch(String URL) {

                      driver.get (URL);
                  }
      }
  ```

Comment: Format and indent your code properly

Comment: Are the above, projects namely: **First project" and "Second project"**, in actual, two different classes in different packages?

Comment: Yes. 'Subh'... thats correct. Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call an instance method of the second class, you have to create an object of the second class and call the method through it. ( "Second" is the class name)

```
Second mySecond = new Second();
mySecond.myMethod();
```

If you want to call a static method of the second class, you can call it by mentioning the second class in following way

```
Second.myMethod();
```